# jquery click handler that passes attribute of clicked object into function?

Tags: jquery, ajax

I have a link like

```
<a href="#" id="foo" class="bar_link">blah</a>
```

I have many of these and the id value is an integer corresponding to a record in a database.

I want to create a click handler to pass the id attribute value for a specific link into a function whenever that link is clicked.

Here is what I have tried, but I am not having success.

```
$(".bar_link").live('click', barDetailsInit($(this).attr('id')));
```

What do you think? Thx!

Comment: I would like to point out that `id` attributes cannot be integers. Consider using `name` instead. (http://stackoverflow.com/questions/70579/what-are-valid-values-for-the-id-attribute-in-html)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This will work

```
$('.bar_link').live('click', function() { 
    barDetailsInit(this.id);
});
```

Comment: It sure does! Thanks so much!

Answer (score 2):

Oops, you forgot to wrap the click event in an anomymous method.

```
$(".bar_link").live('click', function() { barDetailsInit($(this).attr('id')); });
```

Your version would pull `this` as whatever the scope that the line is running in (probably "window").

Answer (score 1):

Try this instead:

```
$(".bar_link").live('click', function(event) {

    barDetailsInit($(this).attr('id')));

});
```

Basically you'll need to call your function from within the event callback, then at that point you have context and can call your function with the desired parameter.